# How many code blocks to cover in (T)source?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Purely because it bugs me, what code block am I missing in my unit tests?
I have a generic mapping method that looks like this:

```
public static dynamic To<T>(dynamic input)
{
    if (input == null || input is DBNull)
    {
        return null;
    }
    try
    {
        return (T)input; // this line remains gray in code coverage
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

I have some simple tests:

```
Assert.Null(Map.To<long>(null));
Assert.Null(Map.To<long>(DBNull.Value));
Assert.AreEqual(20, Map.To<long>(new long?(20)));
Assert.Null(Map.To<long?>("wrong"));
```

Now my code coverage says that I have covered 48 out of 49 blocks. One block is not covered, and it is somewhere in the `return (T)source` line.

I cannot help but think I am overlooking a simple case here...

N.B. This code is not meant to convert everything to anything, it just converts database types to native types in practice. It *will* throw instead of returning `default(T)` before I am done with it.

Comment: Hmm, I've just run my coverage analyzer (DotCover) and it says that `return (T)input;` was executed [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/Cfn16)

Comment: It is executed all right. But not all possible code blocks have been hit. (For example, the `if` in the beginning is always hit, but to hit all codeblocks in `if (A || B)` I need to test for A is true, A is false and B is false, A is false and B is true.

Comment: Regarding your comments: What about `if (A | B)`? This will avoid short circuit evaluation and may cover the last block.